Rectangular Marque and History Can't Work Properly
suddenly my edit options changed, for example for rectangular marque can not be dragged as I want, but become portrait and that is limited. When I try to reset, the marque rectangular become ellipse marque.
The second case, I can not use the history feature to edit the changes that I have made in the previous stages. Can you explain for this?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Have you tried resetting your preferences? Here's how.
